# WordPress, I am making a ranking function but if the post has no eye-catch, it will be counted twice

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
?>
```

I have copied this from the internet and added it to my function php. Afterward, I also included this in my home and index.php.

```
<div class="related-box original-related wow fadeIn cf animated">
<div class="inbox">
    <h2 class="related-h h_ttl">
        <span class="gf">ranking</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="related-post">
<?php


    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => $sticky,
        'posts_per_page' => 8 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) :
            $query->the_post();
?>
            <li rel="bookmark">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="title no-icon">
                <figure class="eyecatch<?php if(!has_post_thumbnail()):?> noimg<?php endif;?>">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail'); } ?>
                    </figure>
                <h3 class="ttl">
                    <p>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); 
                </h3>
            </li>
    
<?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and  `<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>` 
on the top of single.php.

For most of the posts, it works perfectly fine. But for those without an eye-catch, it counts twice. Anybody knows why? I have tried to figure out the problem for days but still have not got a solution, please help.

Comment: Maybe it's just some bot-views? If the code is simply that i can't find any reason of why it should run twice. Either it's some code behind what u've posted or bot-views

Comment: ```function is_bot() {
$ua = !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) : '';
$bot = array(
"googlebot",
"msnbot",
"yahoo"
);
foreach( $bot as $bot ) {
if (stripos( $ua, $bot ) !== false){
return true;
}
}
return false;
}```

```<?php
if( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_bot() ) {
setPostViews(get_the_ID());
} ?><?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>```
I have tried to add this but it does not work...